# How to open then the Android SDK Manager through the terminal?

Tags: android, terminal

I have CD'd into my android tools directory in the terminal. I tried typing 'android' and hitting enter and I also tried typing 'android sdk' and hitting enter but the sdk manager would not come up.

Any solutions or advice to help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If android sdk path is set then 'android sdk' command directly open sdk manager window.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From outside the `tools` directory (obviously, you need to change to suit your path taste):

```
$ sudo /opt/android-sdk-macosx/tools/android
```

From within the `tools` directory (note the leading dot and slash):

```
$ cd /opt/android-sdk-macosx/tools/
$ sudo ./android
```

---

Related: you should have both `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` and `ANDROID_NDK_ROOT` set in your environment. `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` is used by the (now deprecated) `ddms` program. `ANDROID_NDK_ROOT` is used by various NDK tools. See [Recommended NDK Directory?](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-ndk/qZjhOaynHXc/2ux2ZZdxy2MJ) on the Android NDK user list.

Comment: The android command is no longer available.For manual SDK and AVD management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager

Comment: For me, after I did this , and set two roots in ~/.bashrc, it still does not work.