# sdkmanager don't open: I get only [=========] 100% Computing updates

Tags: android, flutter, android-sdk-manager

I had the same problem than here:[How to open Android SDK manager from terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48401422/how-to-open-android-sdk-manager-from-terminal)

That question was marked as duplicated of this one: [How to open then the Android SDK Manager through the terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24372664/how-to-open-then-the-android-sdk-manager-through-the-terminal)

But, as you can see in the comments it's really not a duplicated one because the problem is different.

Anyway, neither of the answers to either question solved the problem for me.

I have downloaded Android SDK, Command line tools only for Windows 10. And when I run: `.\sdkmanager.bat`, I get this message: `[=======================================] 100% Computing updates...` but nothing happens.

I have installed Java and everything seems to be ok.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, I found the solution and I couldn't answer in the above-mentioned questions because both of them are closed.

The problem was that you have to tell `sdkmanager` which libraries do you want to install. So, my solution was run: `sdkmanager --list` to see the last version available and then download the most recent ones for platforms, platform-tools, and build-tools:
`sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-30" "build-tools;30.0.0"`

PS: To be able to create an Android device simulator, I needed to run alse:
`sdkmanager.bat "system-images;android-30;google_apis_playstore;x86"`

Comment: You might have to run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` after that

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/41407396/2171120 apparently there used to be a GUI but Google decided to force Android Studio down users' throats. Visual Studio 2017 has a component called Xamarin Android SDK Manager which apparently can be used, or your command-line solution. How vendor lock-in of Google...